# How to Compare strings by Regex inside a LINQ Query?

Tags: regex, linq, c#-4.0

I have two datatables dtRosterList and falsefields
I want to list out all rosterlist against falsefields ,where list column value is a sentence "Hello i am a list of field" and falsefields column value having a single string "field"...i am matching by Regex.IsMatch

```
Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("ListName"),@"\bFacebook Link\b")
```

is returning true in the Visual studio intermediate window but 
Regex.IsMatch(r.Field("ListName"),@"\b"+fn+"\b") is coming false in Linq query itself and i am getting no rows...The query is below:

```
   var listTobeDeleted = dtRosterList.AsEnumerable().
                             Where(r => falsefields.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(f => f.Field<string>("FieldName")).Any(fn => Regex.Match(r.Field<string>("ListName"),@"\b"+fn+"\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I think you need to go into more detail about the data you are feeding into this. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do or what you are starting with in this post.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems with your code:

- You've used `Regex.Match` instead of `Regex.IsMatch`;
- You've missed the `@` [verbatim string literal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx) prefix on the second `"\b"` string;

  - With the prefix, the string contains two characters: `\` *(ASCII code 92)*, and `b` *(ASCII code 98)*. The Regex engine interprets this to mean *"the match must occur on a boundary between an alphanumeric and a non-alphanumeric character"*.
  - Without the prefix, the string contains a single character: backspace *(ASCII code 8)*. The Regex engine interprets this as a literal character, and so will only match a string containing the backspace character.

I'd also be inclined to add [a `Regex.Escape` call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) around the word to find, in case it contains any special characters.

```
var listTobeDeleted = dtRosterList.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => falsefields.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(f => f.Field<string>("FieldName"))
    .Any(fn => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("ListName"), @"\b" + Regex.Escape(fn) + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: You should explain that `@` is raw string prefix. Just saying that it's a prefix can cause confusion that it's part of regex syntax.